# R class missing in Android sample code

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I create project **from existing Android sample code** but "gen" folder doesn't have R class.

**I tried:**

- Check and uncheck "Build automatically"
- "Clean" the project
- Find the R.java in folder structure but it is not there.

but R class still doesn't appear and the java files keep reporting "R cannot be resolved to a variable".

Using Android 2.2, Eclipse 3.6, Windows XP

Comment: Can you confirm that it is an Android Project in Eclipse?

Comment: Have you tried closing and reopening a couple of times and/or restarting your computer? Don't know why it works here...

Comment: @Haphazard: Sure, I chose "New Android project from existing source"

Comment: Did anyone try to do the same thing like me? :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a brand-new Android project in Eclipse.  Copy the resource files in and then the Java files from the existing project.